# Store only positive,even values from an array into another array

Tags: c, arrays

I create an array, size and values given by the user, and then store only the positive even values into another array, but I only get 0 as answer.

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    float num[10], A[10];

    printf("Enter the numbers of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d. Enter number: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &num[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if(num[i] > 0 && fmod(num[i],2)==0){  
            A[i] = num[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Positive, even values of the new created array are%d\t", A[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `size and values given by the user`...why are you _lying_ ? :)

Comment: `array are%d` --> `array are%f` , and Use loop for output

Comment: Price question: What value does `i` have _after_ your for loop is completely done?

Comment: You need `int j=0;` so that you can do `A[j++] = num[i];`

Comment: Also You need `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: Are you sure you have to use floats instead of integers?

Comment: You probably need two counters, one to cycle through the input array, and one to record where the next entry should go in the second array.  At the end, you'll print the values from the new array.  Note that after the second loop, `A[i]` is not one of the values read from the user, and could be out of bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise `n`. Be careful; `n` should not be greater than 10.

You are printing just one of the values `A[i]`. I guess you want to loop through.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if(num[i] > 0 && fmod(num[i],2)==0){  
       A[i] = num[i];

    printf("Positive, even values of the new created array are %lf\n", A[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Or he intended to print just `i` (i.e. the number of values copied to the array) and not `A[i]` for which the `%d` format specifier is incorrect in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can very simply fill the second array with only *positive* and *even* numbers by checking each value from the first array is greater than or equal to zero, and then by checking whether the bit-0 (the 1-bit) is zero, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % LIM - 4999;         /* random -4999 - 5000 */
        if (a[i] >= 0 && !(a[i] & 1))       /* if pos and even  */
            b[n++] = a[i];                  /* store in b array */
    }
```

(note: the 64 values used for the first array above are random values between `-4999 - 5000` to give a good test of selecting only positive/even numbers.)

After that, you can print both arrays is a reasonable format to easily confirm the operation. Putting all the pieces together, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 64
#define LIM 10000

int main (void) {

    int a[MAX] = {0}, b[MAX] = {0}, n = 0;
    srand (time (NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % LIM - 4999;         /* random -4999 - 5000 */
        if (a[i] >= 0 && !(a[i] & 1))       /* if pos and even  */
            b[n++] = a[i];                  /* store in b array */
    }

    printf ("original array:\n\n");         /* output original array */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (i && (i % 8) == 0)
            putchar ('\n');
        printf (" %5d", a[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    printf ("\npositive even array:\n\n");  /* output pos/even array */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i && (i % 8) == 0)
            putchar ('\n');
        printf (" %5d", b[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrayposeven
original array:

   -68  3112  1571 -1926  1263 -1424   554  3181
  1701 -4545  -956  4442  -431 -2333 -4373  3972
 -3033  2539 -1926   794  4050  1318  3323   120
 -3253  4451   781  2979   519 -2224  4251  1802
 -4113 -2827  1227 -1499 -2899 -3220  3033  3801
 -2765 -2923  3242  1803 -3905   220 -2874  4413
 -2242   200   206 -3193 -3483 -1471 -1722  4615
  4331   410  2593 -3799  3185 -1804  3002   424

positive even array:

  3112   554  4442  3972   794  4050  1318   120
  1802  3242   220   200   206   410  3002   424
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.